# Wordpress is importing my linked stylesheet in-page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm getting a really weird bug on WordPress. I used the following code to import a stylesheet into my template (Which I have used on hundreds of other themes and had no issues);

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sambeckham.com/wp-content/themes/sambeckham/style.css" media="screen" />
```

But for some reason WordPress spits out;

```
<style media="screen" data-href="http://sambeckham.com/wp-content/themes/sambeckham/style.css">
Styles in here
</style>
```

The styles all load fine so I hadn't noticed it till now but I really don't want them in the page. Has anyone ever come across this issue before?

The weirdest thing is that there are 3 stylesheets on this page and the other two link absolutely fine.

Comment: Actually looking at it again it seems to be loading in fine when I view the source but not on the built in Chrome 'inspect element'. Could this be some weird Chrome update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with the version of chrome I was using. The site was processing fine.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't speek to your specific issue (and you've got HTTPAuth blocking access to the blog itself), based on the behavior you're citing, that is not so much a PHP/WordPress issue as much as a Wordpress theme/JavaScript issue. If I were to debug it, my first step would be to comment out each JS file at a time and then see what color smoke comes out.

(It may be necessary to "save the page" as "webpage complete" (or whatever your browser equivalent is) and do that locally as often WordPress has nothing close to best practices...)